# DJI - Why is there delay between two actions in a Timeline?

Tags: dji-sdk

In the aim to add a capture system on a photogrammetric chain, we have studied some solutions proposed in the DJI Mobile SDK Documentation. We have tested the functionalities below :

1. WaypointMission with the shootPhotoTimeInterval of the Waypoint class
2. TimelineElement with the newShootSinglePhotoAction of the shootPhotoAction class

The first way consist by uploading a WaypointMission on the drone. The main drawback of this solution is the limit of the number of waypoints (waypoints are limited until 99 per mission). That implies that the number of images that we can take is limited to 99, If, as we wish, we take one image per waypoint.

The study of the second method show that there is a delay between the execution of 2 consecutive actions of the Timeline. For example, if we make a Timeline with 5 use of the GotoAction class (5 points) in the aim to make a rectangular closed form. Then we launch the Timeline. We can see that once the target point is reached there is a delay before the drone go to the next point.

Here is the code for illustrate the example :

```
final List<TimelineElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();


//Takeoff from the ground
elements.add(new TakeOffAction());


//Go 5 meters from home point
elements.add(new GoToAction(5));


//Go to places different from home point to make a rectangular form and take pictures
elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(x1, y1), 10));
elements.add(ShootPhotoAction.newShootSinglePhotoAction());

elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(x2, y2), 10));
elements.add(ShootPhotoAction.newShootSinglePhotoAction());

elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(x3, y3),10));
elements.add(ShootPhotoAction.newShootSinglePhotoAction());

elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(x4, y4), 10));
elements.add(ShootPhotoAction.newShootSinglePhotoAction());

elements.add(new GoToAction(new LocationCoordinate2D(x5, y5), 10));


//Go home
elements.add(new GoHomeAction());
```

In the aim to find the solution corresponding to our needs, we would like to know why there is a delay . Is it because the next action is upload on the drone only after the previous action is finished ?

Thanks for your help !